# Parallel development for iOS & Android Mobile app using react Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new for React Native. I have experience build application for web using react JS. But I have requirement to build Native apps for Android & iOS.

Is same source code of application will use to build mobile app for Android & iOS both. or I have to do development separately for Android or iOS.

Or I can create build using Android environment on windows and same source code will use to build iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

For React-native you want to first install Nodejs on your device then after very easy to install react-native.

the Facebook provide sufficient guide to integrate your system for developing react-native app.

[react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Yes that is ok. am I need to maintain source code differently for IOS & Android app or I can build cross platform for both ?

Comment: then you want to differenciat your way:

Comment: like manage diff index.ios and index.android file and other files also.

Answer (score 0):

I started to learn react-native 5month ago and I'm programming Android and IOS app on an Android / Windows environment.

It is globally the same code 98% but they are exceptions that constrain you to test on an IOS device.

examples: fonts are not the same on Android and IOS, Splash screen, webview.... have different behaviours.

So in conclusion. If you want to make an IOS app you will have to debug / test on an IOS device however you can code all your app on a windows / android environment (like me)  with ios simulator and test/debug it at the end on IOS device.